# My jupiter notebook is taking long minutes before giving any output(keeps running) when I write this particular piece of code

Tags: pandas, datetime

```
for j in range(len(datelist)):
    tempmax.append((df.where(df['Date']==datelist[j])['Data_Value'].max()))
    tempmin.append((df.where(df['Date']==datelist[j])['Data_Value'].min()))

print(tempmax)
```

When I write this piece of code my Jupiter notebook keeps running for around 10 minutes before providing any output

Comment: What is the shape of df and datelist?

Comment: df is a dataframe consisting of 16000 rows and datelist is a list consisting of 3600 entries

Answer (score 0):

For of all, you can increase your speed by skipping pd.where()

Speed comparison:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = range(16000)
df['b'] = range(16000)

%timeit df.where(df['a']==2)['b'].max()
>>> 6.31 ms ± 124 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df[df['a']==2]['b'].max()
>>> 777 µs ± 8.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Your new code should run roughly 10x as fast:

```
for j in range(len(datelist)):
    tempmax.append((df[df['Date']==datelist[j]]['Data_Value'].max()))
    tempmin.append((df[df['Date']==datelist[j]]['Data_Value'].min()))
```

It's also possible that using pd.Series.agg() will speed things up even more:

```
for j in range(len(datelist)):
    search = df[df['Date']==datelist[j]].agg(['max','min'])['Data_Value']
    tempmax.append(search['max'])
    tempmin.append(search['min'])
```

Comment: 'Series' object has no attribute 'agg' ----this error message showing when I am trying to use pd.Series.agg()

Comment: I tried doing it by removing pd.where() and it still is taking as much time as earlier

Comment: Can you try the .agg() method? I've updated my answer.

Comment: This time its showing a message--- 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg'

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? pd.agg() was new in version 0.20

Comment: That seems to be the problem I am using version 0.19 and I can't change the version as its from a third party

Comment: I think I miss-typed the number of rows of df; its 160,000